# Why can I have differing signatures for a function's definition and declaration?

Tags: c, function

Consider the following program (inspired by the Tcl source code [here](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/blob/61317caad1a51589029679818be0470c99d704b7/generic/panic.c#L24)):

**test.h**

```
void func(char* format, ...);
```

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define func funcDummy
#include "test.h"
#undef func

void func(char *format, char *arg)
{
    printf(format, arg);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void) argc;
    (void) argv;
    func("I'm %s\n", "confused");
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles with no warnings using `gcc main.c test.c -Wall -Wextra` and outputs "I'm confused."

I would expect to see an error about there being an unresolved reference to function func. What's going on that makes this okay?

Comment: You’d expect to see an unresolved reference to function func because the definition in test.c doesn’t match the prototype that main.c used, or…?

Comment: @Ry- You'd expect that in C++, not C. It just uses the function name for linking, the signature is ignored.

Comment: @Barmar: I never said *I’d* expect that, I was asking if that’s why the OP expected that :P

Comment: I thought you were using the generic "you", not referring to the OP specifially.

Comment: I'd like to see the original code so I can better understand why someone would do this. Seems bonkers to me.

Comment: If Tcl does something like this, that's rather worrying.

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to the original code. Note that this is a particularly old version of the library.

Comment: @Ry- Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works because C doesn't have mangled names. In C, the symbol name is 'func'. In C++, the symbol name would be somethings like '_Zblahblah_func_blahblah_E'. C++ encodes the arguments into the symbol name (used by the linker later). C does not.

test.c defines the function void func(char *format, char *arg).

when compiling main.c, the compiler sees: 'void func(char* format, ...);'

The linker however, will refer to both as simply 'func'. When the linker sees the call in main.c, it sees the definition for func as simply 'func' (args be damned).

It just so happens, that the args you've passed to it in main.c, happen to be compatible with those expected in func.c, and so it magically works.

If you were instead to change the files to 'cpp' instead of 'c', you'll have a linker error (since the mangled names for both prototypes, will not match, and you'll have a linker error)

TL;DR: C++ supports function overloading, C does not.

Comment: The arguments are not compatible as far as the language is concerned. The declaration of `func` says it's variadic. The definition says it isn't. Variadic and non-variadic functions can have entirely different calling conventions, so the behavior is undefined.  (Most implementations are likely to make it "work" -- which is, as always, one possible consequence of undefined behavior.)

Comment: C's rather loose linking behavior is why it's important that `file_x.c` always include `file_x.h` for normal cases. That way you'll get compilation errors/warnings while `file_x.c` is being compiled if the prototypes and definitions do not match.